# The business network didn't upgrade on IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I need to upgrade my hyperledger composer business network on IBM. I had already started one business network on IBM cloud. But once I upgrade my **bna** on **IBM cloud** it throws an *error* that is

`Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: received trailing metadata size exceeds limit`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be you have run out of resources to start a new chaincode container. One thing you can try is to stop all your peers and then restart them. This should kill all the chaincode containers (ones which may still be hanging around from previous upgrades that are not used anymore) and would only start the latest chaincodes that are registered to channels once you make your first request, which can be your upgrade request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I had removed old peer and Started a new chain code. But it did not work for me. When I start my Business network again get the same error. Any Idea How can I check my available resources spaces on IBM ?

Comment: I assume you are using Starter or Enterprise plan ? then you will have to raise a support ticket I think

Comment: I am using the Enterprise plan.

Comment: I suggest you raise a support ticket with IBM

Comment: Actually I am not an owner of the IBM account which I have used for deployment so I can't create a support ticket. But I'm using this[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzNF-5pdxdk] tutorial. You have any idea about it or any tutorials then please give me a suggestion.

Comment: On enterprise plan, as the fabric environment is a managed service, issues relating to resource will usually require assistance from IBM support. The only user option I know of was to stop and start your peers to clear out any old running chaincode containers. You might want to talk to the account owner.

Comment: Okay, Thank You! I will contact to owner. Actually I am getting [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/dui4h93jf/raw/upload/v1570625081/peer_logs_zjgl0m.txt) logs in peer when I trying to start a business network.

Comment: That output doesn't look good. There appears to be a mixture of different composer components levels, plus it's is trying to use a version of grpc it shouldn't be using. I suggest looking at your package.json file for your bna and remove any references to composer npm modules. composer network install will inject the correct versions in for you.

Comment: Thanks! But there are no references to composer npm modules in package.json file.

Comment: Ok, strange that there is a mixture of versions then. Are you still using composer 0.19.5 ? If you are you should move to 0.19.20